# Text cursor in xcode isn't typing. blinking rectangle instead of a blinking line

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, text-editor

I'm using Xcode on a system that belonged to a former employe and I can't type. There's a weird rectangle text cursor blinking and a blank line at the bottom that responds to my key types in a weird manner. If I press a key the text cursor will just get smaller. There's also the location path of the file I'm currently on, I'd also like that to be removed. Thanks

[image]

added numbers in red next to each problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XVim.xcplugin <-- that was the file causing all of this. After deletion and relunch everything is back to normal. You can find more information about it here: https://github.com/WarWithinMe/xVim

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your former employee might have customized Xcode or, more possibly, customized the Macintosh to be non-vanilla (maybe it's a Text Input Entry setting or some internationalization or some third party extension or preference pane).

Try doing this:  go to the "Text Editing" preferences within Xcode and toggle a few things to see if you have better luck.  If that doesn't work, create a new user on the Macintosh and then launch and run Xcode from that new user account.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. When I press A the blank line says -- INSERT --. when I press Q is says RECORDING. I'd like to solve this without creating a new user.

Comment: Ooof, it sure sounds like you have some extra third party software installed. Any obvious non-Apple preference panes in System Preferences?  Or is Universal Access enabled?

Comment: no and no :\ Everything looks normal. Is there an xcode addons panel I can check?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm out of ideas at this point, but I will upvote your question and hopefully somebody else will know what kind of extension might be causing this bad behavior.

Comment: Just an update. I've created a new user on the system and Xcode works fine there so I'm pretty convinced that this is some sort of plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is composed by XVim.xcpluginxc. By deleting this we get free from this issue. For this issue. Please follow these steps.

```
 1.Open the terminal.
 2.Type "find ~/ XVim.xcpluginxc". This will list your entire system with this particular file/folder name.
 3.From that list copy that particular path having this folder.
 4.Type "rm -Rf path that you copied earlier".
 5.Press "Enter".
 6.type "exit".
```

Finally close the Terminal & Restart the Xcode.