# Looking for Xcode settings folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

So after this question: [Text cursor in xcode isn't typing. blinking rectangle instead of a blinking line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090883/text-cursor-in-xcode-isnt-typing-blinking-rectangle-instead-of-a-blinking-line/14090952#comment19489136_14090952) wasn't answered I've created a new user on the system and xcode works fine there so, I went back to the old username and started to search for suspicious files around the system. I'm looking for any Xcode user related folder that can hold any kind of settings for me to delete.
I can't reset xcode from the terminal (that would be just like using the new user I've created) because there are a lot of provision keys and a lot of recent Data in xcode I don't want to lose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and kill all the preference files: any of the Xcode related items in `~/Library/Preferences`

And then you could delete shared data:

`~/Library/Application Support/Shared/`

and

`~/Library/Developer/`

Comment: most of the Xcode settings are in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

Comment: @AntonKukoba thank you for that path. It really is where most of the visuals, account settings and such are stored.